# При каждом последующем вызове функции переменная срабатывает по несколько раз

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, таблицы

**Постановка задачи**. Таблицу нужно оснанстить возможностью удалять из неё определённые строки. Нажимаем на слово удалить в строке -> открывается модальное меню, где пользователя переспрашивают о том, что точно удалить или отменить удаление. Нажав на кнопку модального окна "Удалить" из таблицы должна исчезнуть соответствующая строка.

**Разметка**

Есть разметка c таблицей. Два столбца, первый с идентификатором, а второй с каким-то текстом. Первая строка - шапка, а оставльные - обычные строки:

```
  <table id="table_main">

    <tr> <th>id</th> <th>Текст задачи</th>  <th>Действия</th> </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>  <td>Текст 1</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>  <td>Текст 2</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>  <td>Текст 3</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>  <td>Текст 4</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>  <td>Текст 5</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>  <td>Текст 6</td>  <td><p class="delete">Удалить</p></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

И модальным окном:

```
  <div class="modal_delete">

    <div id="modal_button_container">
      <button id="button_delete">Удалить</button>
      <button id="button_cancel">Отмена</button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Мой **скрипт**

```
/*Скрипт удаления задачи*/
$(".delete").click(function () {
    // Определяем номер строки по нажатому p
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().index();

    // Делаем модальное окно видимым
    $(".modal_delete").css("display", "flex");

    // Кнопка удаления
    $("#button_delete").click(function () {

        // Скрываем модальное окно
        $(".modal_delete").hide();

        // Удаляем строку
        $("#table_main").children().children().eq(num).remove(); // (1)

    });

});
```

В чём **ПРОБЛЕМА**?

Первый раз функция срабатывает отлично. Но при каждом последующем её вызове происходит удаление уже нескольких строчек. Через консоль браузера выявил, что строчка кода (*) срабатывает несколько раз: при первом вызове один раз, при втором - дважды, при третьем - трижды и т.д. При этом видно, что значение переменной num каждый раз меняется.

Например, если я нажимаю на "Удалить" строк 1 - 3 - 5, то при втором вызове функции num будет равняться 3, когда сработает строка (1) с num 3, то значение num поменяется на предыдущее - 1, и строка (1) сработает ещё раз. При третьем вызове значения num будут меняться в таком порядке: 5 - 3 - 1 (то есть обратном).

Почему это num меняет своё значение? Я такое поведение переменных вижу впервые.

**Вопрос**: как обеспечить срабатываение строки (*) единожды? как сделать так, чтобы значение num было единственным?

ПС. Альтернативные решения задачи тоже принимаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том что вы вешали листенер каждый раз когда нажималась кнопка "удалить" (не в модалке)

немного исправил ваш код что-бы он стал рабочим

```
var num = null
$(".delete").click(function () {
    // Определяем номер строки по нажатому p
    num = $(this).parent().parent().index();

    // Делаем модальное окно видимым
    $(".modal_delete").css("display", "flex");

});

// Кнопка удаления
$("#button_delete").click(function () {

  // Скрываем модальное окно
  $(".modal_delete").hide();

  // Удаляем строку
  $("#table_main").children().children().eq(num).remove(); // (1)

});
```

Comment: Вот это оно! Благодарю!